# Increase y range for `geom_line()` in `ggplot`

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data

```
> dput(df_ggplot)
structure(list(time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
21, 22, 23, 24, 25), prices = c(-0.30006834352587, -0.00555487442073247, 
0.258679288900665, 0.439432386185049, 0.216483899258755, -0.07180776590316, 
-0.244214595104925, -0.014369355833968, -0.130494093735835, -0.0993524071519092, 
0.0417262548938068, 0.029683613288831, -0.336259749313202, 0.0432942972908209, 
0.198346778977676, -0.0609698937346443, 0.162074965376874, 0.362756477084522, 
-0.201537845483782, -0.218935082840323, 0.0617031438039988, -0.11493961918202, 
0.133697792972297, -0.0614481093677531, -0.311669297606833, -0.30006834352587, 
0.0819856942951882, 0.163636220849344, 0.985956325310659, -0.16096684463549, 
-0.0806455784199295, -0.134650534646189, -0.0674387029421786, 
0.0809173564567764, -0.175459007730146, 0.0405360847200064, -0.189403033958823, 
-0.217194929585943, -0.122518388961322, 0, 0.0953136827739254, 
0, 0.25794826085627, -0.366890546975166, -0.0136316982929607, 
-0.0272726870548112, -0.0682359777640138, -0.0409788500441341, 
0.0819297440769776, -0.314673133835946), variable = c("simulated", 
"simulated", "simulated", "simulated", "simulated", "simulated", 
"simulated", "simulated", "simulated", "simulated", "simulated", 
"simulated", "simulated", "simulated", "simulated", "simulated", 
"simulated", "simulated", "simulated", "simulated", "simulated", 
"simulated", "simulated", "simulated", "simulated", "data", "data", 
"data", "data", "data", "data", "data", "data", "data", "data", 
"data", "data", "data", "data", "data", "data", "data", "data", 
"data", "data", "data", "data", "data", "data", "data")), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = "data.frame")
```

With `ggplot`

```
ggplot(data=df_ggplot,aes(x=time, y=prices, colour=variable))+ geom_line()
```

I obtain the following picture:
[image]
It is fine, but I would like to enlarge the y axis scale, which i would like to be in range (e.g.) [0,2].

Comment: `ggplot(data=df_ggplot,aes(x=time, y=prices, colour=variable))+ geom_line() + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 2))`. However, `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-1, 2)` looks more sensible?

Comment: `lb <- min(df_ggplot$prices)
ub <- max(df_ggplot$prices)

ggplot(data = df_ggplot, aes(x = time, y = prices, colour = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(
    expand = c(0, 0),
    limits = c(min = lb, max = ub))`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example where I extend the axis to [-0.5, 1]. You can add in additional breaks in the y-axis as well. If you set the y-axis limits to [0,1], you would cut off a lot of your series!

I often calculate the lower or upper bounds of the data and round up or down a little to rounder numbers then create a sequence of breaks as desired, but you can do whatever you'd like.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = df_ggplot, aes(x = time, y = prices, colour = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(
    expand = c(0, 0),
    limits = c(min = -0.5, max = 1.0),
    breaks = seq(-0.5, 1, by = 0.1))
```

[image]

UPDATED: As @Limey mentions in the comments, this can also be done with `coord_cartesian()`, although notice the consequences for the x-axis labels.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = time, y = prices, colour = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = seq(-0.5, 1, by = 0.1)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-0.5,1.0),
                  expand = FALSE)
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = time, y = prices, colour = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = seq(-0.5, 1, by = 0.1)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-0.5,1.0),
                  expand = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: I stongly urge against using `limits` in a scale function to set the axis limits.  `coord_cartesian()` is vastly preferable, IMHO.  The reason is that `coord_cartesian()` uses the full data set to construct the plot and then *"zooms"* to the required area.  A scale function with limits first *filters* the data set and then plots the graph.   That's not an issue here, but if any interpolation, model fitting, or calculation of summary statistics involved in the construction of the graph, it can lead to errors that are difficult to detect.  Best avoid bad habits at all times!

Comment: @Limey Added examples with `coord_cartesian()`. A little puzzled why setting the y-axis with it causes the x-axis labels to disappear for x = 0 and why the expand argument adds them back to be identical to the `limits` examples.